# Should "йе" after vowel be pronounced [jje]?

Tags: орфография, буквы, фонология

я, ю, е letters are pairs for а, у, э, and, мае should be read maje, and майе should be read majje, like it happens with мая and майя - maja and majja.

Right?

I, personally, think that э is a different vowel than е in modern Russian, unlike vowels in я-а, ю-у pairs, ie I think мяч and мач have same а, but only different м, but in case of мер and мэр I think the vowels are different. I do not know how old is this situation, but according to general logic that appear, е is just the match for э like я is for а, seems it was so historically. I do not ask about this, this is just to show the problem. I, personally, used to wrongly think that айе should be read aje just like ае, because I thought that е generally behaves differently from я and ю... For example, I thought, it does not change the m in меч, does not palatalize it, like it happens in мяч, so I thought, е has initial j only in beginning of word, so, I thought, е's behaviour after й is just like after any other consonant, while я after й should use its initial j and make a double j.

Some letter sequences here are not meaningful words, they are just examples, the question is about how letter sequence should be read.

This question is to get a proof to fix a wiktionary function/table, (I do not know what is it and how named), for https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User_talk:Benwing2#reading_of_%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B5_etc , for table in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F and other similar words.

Adding on December 18:

Some answers are about what happens in real speech. I think there is some current canonical Russian writing system, where should be a simple general rule, reading (pronouncing) according to which is not incorrect, it is correct, acceptable because it is canonical, generally it maybe a little archaic, not like people really speak, but ok. For example, pronouncing "gripəm" (or maybe there should be other thing instead of ə, i am not sure, it is not important for this question) maybe what is used by more people and more often, but if somebody says "grippəm" or "grippom" it is not incorrect, because it is somewhat canonical. I think using such canonical version would be more correct to use in a table in Wiktionary. I asked about such "canonical Russian writing system", not about current etymological/phonetical processes / phases of processes / changes "in the wild" (sound shifts etc). Also some little known pronouncing rules maybe not known, not noticed by some people, and may be pronounced by them without that rule, as it is written, or there maybe dialectal differences.

Adding on January 10, 2019:

Should "йе" after vowel be pronounced [jje]? Should [jje] after vowel be written "йе" or "ййэ" or "ййе"? Should [je] after vowel be written "е" or "йэ" or "йе"?

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Like - My question is - ....

Comment: @shabunc, i added links, see

Comment: I'm sorry, but a link per se doesn't count as a question clarification. Links tend to become invalid, and question supposed to be self-sufficient.

Comment: @shabunc, i do not think that my question is not specific, it is yes or no question. please remove "hold" if you can.

Comment: don't get me wrong, my goal is to make this question relevant enough so that you'll have valid answer - so, is your question is about - what's the difference between мая and, say,  майя ? 

Can you please clarify.

Comment: @shabunc, is phonetic transcription of майе - majje (or maje)? generally, is phonetic transcription of vowel-й-е is vowel-jje or vowel-je?

Comment: I've edited the title - if you don't mind and believe that this make things clearer - let's go with it.

Comment: @shabunc, i do not like your new edit, я at beginning of word is different, i ask about in middle of word after vowel, and i ask specifically about йе, because е is a little different from я,ю as i explained, (and from ё), i have seen problems only with йе.

Comment: please, don't just rerevert title - there's reason why it was edited  (also, is used twice).

Comment: "in case of мер and мэр I think the vowels are different. I do not know how old is this situation" - i think, it must be from beginning, because if i try to say [м][э], [мь][э], [м][е], [мь][е], the last 2 of these, for me, are indistinguishable while listening to them. the 2nd is quite hardly distinguishable from the last 2. so they might be developed to be pronounced that way from beginning.

Comment: i have written a new question at https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4914507.html , and during writing that new post, i have found out, that майе is majje phonologically, because its root is majj and suffix e, like knige is knig+e, bate is bat(j)+e. so, all forms of majja should have double j. сойер and лукойе should have single j-s, because they have single j-s in original language. but my question is about russian writing system, not about these particular words.

Comment: correction to the last (previous) comment (in this thread) : i said "during writing that new post, i have found out" - this is not correct. i knew this long time ago. i have just written it down at this time.

Comment: new question: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/448157

Answer (score 5):

Gemination is a bit fuzzy in Russian:

1. Words such as **касса, масса, тонна, ванна, Мекка, поддать, [Приенисейе](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=02xgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=t2TOT5If94&sig=Y09tLFqQoTpszXUz-bCW_PQUubI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYmOeluK7fAhVYVRUIHbTlClUQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5&f=false)** [йй] have 'true doubles': saying them with a single consonant can hinder understanding. Minimal pairs: **подать - поддать, подождём - под дождём,** (нет) **тона - тонна, при Енисее - Приенисейе.**
2. Then there are 'false doubles' which are normally pronounced as singles: **аппарат, аккуратный, [теннис](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81#Pronunciation),** (болеть) **[гриппом](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC).** Saying them with a double consonant would sound inappropriate in normal speech but could be used e.g. to explain how the word is spelled.
3. The rest of the words occupy a middle ground whereby they can be pronounced with either single or double consonants or anywhere in between without sounding odd or erroneous. These include: [русский](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9#Pronunciation), [рассказ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7), [зажаренный](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), Майя, майя, Айя-София and many others. Actual pronunciation may depend on the speaker or the meaning ([Майя](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F) vs [майя](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F#Pronunciation)).

The word **длина** is a very peculiar case as it is sometimes erroneously pronounced with a double [нн].

As for your December 18 update ("if somebody says "grippəm" or "grippom" it is not incorrect, because it is somewhat canonical"):

- Я заболел гри**пп**ом.
- Я пошел играть в те**нн**ис.
- А**пп**арат вызываемого абонента недоступен.

If you say these sentences with 'proper' doubles, people would think you are imitating an Estonian accent or trying to spell the words out. It would sound improper and incorrect.

Comment: "High-frequency words sometimes lose gemination (in speech, not in writing) which is what happened to русский and Майя (the female name)." - i do not think they have lost gemination, especially in slow speach, you can see video example for Майя in shabunc's answer, and see https://forvo.com/word/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F/ and https://forvo.com/word/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/ , i feel double с here, it is somewhat more strong and longer than if it would be с.

Comment: see addition to my question...

Comment: https://forvo.com/word/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC/ - 2 recordings both "gripəm". https://forvo.com/word/%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82/ - for me, 3 out of the current 7 are apparat.

Comment: for somebody may not understand, предъюбилейе and Приенисейе are of nominative case.

Comment: https://forvo.com/word/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/ - 1 of 2 are akkuratniy. https://forvo.com/word/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81/ - i think, 3 of 7 are tennis.

Comment: the recordings of tennis, russkiy, rasskaz on wiktionary are with double consonants.

Comment: for me, 10 of 10 recordings of russkiy, 9 of 9 recordings of rasskaz, 1 of 1 recordings of зажаренный on forvo are with double consonants, even if they do not sound clearly double, they are other than single consonant (longer, stronger).

Comment: "could be used e.g. to explain how the word is spelled" - let's think that there should be simple reading rule for russian letters, thus, reading "майе" like "ma - i kratkiy - je", using alphabet names, should be not needed, then, should it be read "majje" or "maje" by dictor to writer, in order to transfer it from script to script via air without losses?

Comment: @qdinar, I've just asked a 35 y.o. native speaker with no linguistic training to spell Майя Плисецкая (I emphasized the double й) and they spelled it without the Й the first time around. So I would say it would depend on the level of literacy of the listener/writer.

Comment: Then I asked them if they would say a double Н in теннис, and the answer was "of course, because it's spelled with a double Н". But after I've said the phrase "Я вышел из ванной и пошел играть в теннис", emphasizing the double НН in both words, she agreed that теннис sounds weird when said with the double НН while ванной does not.

Comment: Forvo recordings are *not* normal paced speech: the readers see the words written and they say them in isolation which makes them lean towards the idealistic pronunciation of "how it's written".

Comment: Another pecular example is раса which is pronounced with double c.

Answer (score 4):

For `я` in `майя` there's such difference, it's supposed to be pronounced like `май-йа`. However, for instance, de-facto this quite exotic letter combination is pronounced just like `я`. For verifying both of the claims you can search youtube for `Майя Плисецкая` (like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkJ21e3Qt5c)) and `Айя-София` (like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpkK4IZRrOE)).

`Йе` is actually pronounced just like `е` ([je]) - so Том Сойер would have been pronounced identically has it have been spelled `Том Соер` - this spelling does not exist for historical reasons just like we spell `йогурт`, not `ёгурт`.

Generally speaking gemination is not something very typical for Russian - however it do [exist to some extent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#Russian) - but specifically about `йй` one can claim it's virtually non-existent.

Comment: The video for **Айя-София** that you linked to clearly says it with a double **йй**.

Comment: also in the video he says clearly majja, for me.

Comment: first video is soviet time video, dictors, as i know were higly trained and selected, and pronounciation norms on media were controlled by state. there should be somewhat canonical pronounciation. so it verifies how it is supposed to be pronounced. to say about the second video i have to learn about its author. i think, he reads just correctly, and there is not contradiction between how it is should be and how it is pronounced. in both i hear jj. so, only first of your claims verified. and how contradictory claims could be verified by same videos?

Comment: at https://forvo.com/word/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80/ i see transcription as Tom Soyyer and 2 recordings first somewhat like with jj or with o:j (longer o), second is with j.

Comment: i think the writing as сойер might have been a mistake, while it should had been сойэр or соер.

Comment: "just like we spell йогурт, not ёгурт" - but it is not йёгурт.

Comment: @qdinar well, if you disagree, you disagree, not that much I can do.

Comment: another similar example is йеллоустон. i think, it also could be a mistake, that it should had been йэллоустон or еллоустон. though, that mistake might be affected by the fact that э sounds differently in modern russian than е, so they wanted not to write йэллоустон, and they had some strange tradition to have a separate letter for j in foreign words, so they could not use еллоустон.

Comment: > also in the video he says clearly majja, for me 
this is exactly what I've stated

Comment: i said "that mistake might be affected by the fact that э sounds differently in modern russian than е" - in case of еллоустон-йэллоустон, they sound similar. also соер-сойэр. instead, they might be affected by already established tradition to {use e instead of э in most of words so that э had started to look like a different vowel}.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what all the paragraph about what you thought on Е and Э is aimed at. If we decided to write **айэ**, it would sound just like **ае**: **в мае**. Unless we would like to make an extra effort to show this unusual combination in speech.

It is impossible to soften й.

The letters **я, ю, ё, е** do sound as **йа, йу, йо, йэ** in the alphabet, and also after vowels, ь, ъ and й. In the latter case the sound й is reduplicated, but any consonant reduplication is partially reduced (say, to 1 1/2), so it can still sound as 1 **й** in fluent speech. But when we pronounce it distinctly we do have something like **йй** there.

The declension of the word **майя** on the second link is weird. You can decline only **Майя** as a name, but it requires a capital letter. Besides, why is there no Genitive in plural? The word **майя** meaning the Maya people is indeclinable in Russian.

Comment: "It is not quite clear what all the paragraph about what you thought on Е and Э is aimed at.0 If we decided to write айэ, it would sound just like ае: в мае." - as i said, i think, that in modern russian э is usually read differently than э inside е. i think, айэ would usually be pronounced like ajæ, and ае like aje. (see the difference between мер and мэр: https://forvo.com/word/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80/ , https://forvo.com/word/%D0%BC%D1%8D%D1%80/ ). and this might affect how people started to use е after й, as i shown in comments to shabunc's answer.

Comment: "If we decided to write айэ, it would sound just like ае: в мае." - so, i think, you give a little prove to the idea, that i said about, that historically "е is just the match for э like я is for а".

Comment: "But when we pronounce it distinctly we do have something like йй there." - so you say about what i asked/clarified in addition to my question: the double jj version is canonical, because distinct pronounciation here means canonical pronounciation...

Answer (score -1):

i have come to idea/conclusion that writting vowel + й + я/е/ю/ё should be avoided because they are ambiguous, it should be replaced with vowel + я/е/ю/ё for single j, vowel + й + ь + я/е/ю/ё for double j. i have written this as an answer at https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/449850 .

> Should “йе” after vowel be pronounced [jje]? я, ю, е letters are pairs
>   for а, у, э, and, мае should be read maje, and майе should be read
>   majje, like it happens with мая and майя - maja and majja. Right?

-- i think now: no, since й is a consonont, it should behave like other consonants, and should not create second [j] (double [j]). (я does not create an additional consonant when used after a consonant, but, it just palatalizes it. also е/ю/ё).

> Should [jje] after vowel be written "йе" or "ййэ" or "ййе"?

-- neither, "йе" is ambiguous, "ййэ" and "ййе" are strange, not cyrillic, since they use йэ or йе instead of е, and "ййэ" is not correct if it is in a russian suffix, because э is used to mean a different vowel, that is used in loanwords, in positions except beginning of word. in case it is not russian [jje] but the [jjæ], that may be in loanwords, then ййэ should be used.

> Should [je] after vowel be written "е" or "йэ" or "йе"?

-- "е". "йэ" to show the different vowel that may be in loanwords.